# Reposted tracks by authenticated user (/me/activities)?

Tags: soundcloud

I created test account on SoundCloud and tried to use me/activities API for getting recent activities. Test account have exactly 30 activities (reposted playlists - 6; created playlists - 1; reposted tracks - 23). With limit=1 parameter I’m receiving exactly 23 activities, and 16 of them are empty like this:

```
{
"collection":[],
"next_href":"https://api.soundcloud.com/me/activities?cursor=9b768680-9ecc-11e3-805c-3a36c8290708\u0026limit=1”,
"future_href":"https://api.soundcloud.com/me/activities?limit=1\u0026uuid%5Bto%5D=6fdfc300-9fd6-11e3-80b5-0fd1bb49c7d8”
}
```

Other 7 containing info that contains reposts from users I follow, and created playlist.
So my question is, what I’m doing wrong? Is it supposed to happen? And, if so, is there any way to know all the activity?
I’m doing an iOS app, and it seems like native SoundCloud app doing that just fine. Is it using special API, that is’t available for public?

Thanks in advance.